# How to load data from csv into numpy array using pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I want to load csv rows into a numpy array using pandas library. I can read the csv using pandas but havent found any function that allows reading row by row in csv file.

How do I read row by row from csv using pandas and put it into an array?

ex.

```
     Parch            Ticket      Fare        Cabin Embarked  
0        0         A/5 21171    7.2500          NaN        S  
1        0          PC 17599   71.2833          C85        C
```

I want to create a list of lists like this:

```
[
[0, "A/5", 21171, 7.2500, NaN, "S"],
[0, "PC", 17599, 71.2833, "C85", "C"]
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First convert to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) and then [`ndarray.tolist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html):

```
print (df.values)
[[0 'A/5 21171' 7.25 nan 'S']
 [0 'PC 17599' 71.2833 'C85' 'C']]

print (df.values.tolist())
[[0, 'A/5 21171', 7.25, nan, 'S'], [0, 'PC 17599', 71.2833, 'C85', 'C']]
```