# Convert a csv file to array uisng pandas

Tags: python-3.x

I have a csv file as shown below

Year, Growth 
1,    10 
2,    12 
3,    13 
4,   15

I would like to convert content of the csv file to an array say my_array,
so that I can access growth as show below

my_array[1] should return 10

my_array[4] should return 15 etc

How can I convert the csv to such an array using  pandas?

Comment: This is what is you are looking for (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238848/how-to-load-data-from-csv-into-numpy-array-using-pandas)

Comment: But I need to access values as my_array[4]. Is it possible with that?

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> import pandas
>>> df = pandas.read_csv('test.csv')
>>> df
   Year  Growth
0      1      10
1      2      12
2      3      13
3      4      15
>>> arr = df['Growth'].values.tolist()
>>> arr[0]
10
```

Yes , above piece of code will help you do that for whatever columns you want.